# Can I use Iron-ajax to load data to polymer/highcharts element

Tags: jquery, highcharts, polymer

I am trying to create a polymer element that creates a Highchart. I am having trouble getting the ajaxResponse to be read in the script tags. I tried to move the chart constructor inside the template but still not working, error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

```
script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<dom-module id="sales-chart">
    <template>

        <iron-ajax auto url="http://127.0.0.1:3412/2" handle-as="json" last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>

        <div id="container" style="max-width: 600px; height: 360px;"> HELLO <span>{{ajaxResponse.series}}</span></div>


        <script> 


            $("#container").highcharts({

            chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {text:  'Company Sales '},
            series: [this.$.ajaxResponse]

        })

        </script>


    </template>

    <script>


        Polymer({
          is: "sales-chart",

        });

    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: I am trying the following but get error:'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined'

Comment: It seems the ajaxResponse can't be read in the script tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can! Give this a go:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<link href="../../iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="bar-chart">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax id="ajax" url="{{url}}" last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>
    <div id="container" style="max-width: 600px; height: 360px;"></div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "bar-chart",

      properties: {
        url: String,
        data: Object
      },

      observers: [
        // These functions only run once the observed properties contain
        // something other than undefined.
        '_requestData(url)',
        '_chartData(data)'
      ],

      _requestData: function(url) {
        // Note: Use `generateRequest()` instead of the `auto` property
        // because `url` may not be available when your element is
        // first created.
        this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
      },

      _chartData: function (data) {
        $(this.$.container).highcharts({
          chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            renderTo: 'container'
          },
          title: {text:  'HI'},
          xAxis: {
            categories: ['London', 'Paris', 'Madrid']
          },
          yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: 'Sales'
            }
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'Cities',
            data: data.series
          }]
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Another tip: rather than importing jQuery and highcharts with `<script>` tags, you should create an additional html file in your component directory that loads them with `<script>` tags, and then import that file in your component.  This way, if your component is itself imported multiple times, it won't needlessly fetch the scripts multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Zikes it works, I changed the following to get data into chart:

Comment: _chartData: function (data) {
        $(this.$.container).highcharts({
          chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            renderTo: 'container'
          },
         
          series: [{
            
            data: (data.series)
          }]
        });

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'll update my answer to reflect that change.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Highcharts-Chart](https://github.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart) component you could simply do this:

```html
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/highcharts-chart/highcharts-chart.html">

<highcharts-chart type="bar" data="{{ajaxData}}" x-label="Cities"></highcharts-chart>
<iron-ajax auto url="http://127.0.0.1:3412/2" handle-as="json" last-response="{{ajaxData}}"></iron-ajax>
```

Simple as that! And the component itself handles the jQuery, and Highcharts dependencies for you.

**OR**

If you wanted to be more *pedantic* with the way you insert your data:

- As a stream of new Data:

  ```html
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/highcharts-chart/highcharts-chart.html">

  <highcharts-chart id="chart" type="bar" x-label="Cities"></highcharts-chart>
  <iron-ajax auto url="http://127.0.0.1:3412/2" handle-as="json" on-response="handleAjax"></iron-ajax>

  <script>
     app.handleAjax = function(e){app.$.chart.addData(e.detail.response.label,e.detail.response.height)}
  </script>
  ```
- As new data to be re-mapped

  ```html
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/highcharts-chart/highcharts-chart.html">

  <highcharts-chart id="chart" type="bar" x-label="Cities"></highcharts-chart>
  <iron-ajax auto url="http://127.0.0.1:3412/2" handle-as="json" on-response="handleAjaxWithChange"></iron-ajax>
  <script>
      app.handleAjaxWithChange = function(e){
          app.$.chart.setData(e.detail.response.forEach((el)=>{
              return [el.City+", "+el.State, el.count]
          }))
      }
  </script>
  ```

There are more examples [here](http://avdaredevil.github.io/highcharts-chart/).